# videojs with hls plugin: how to limit retries

Tags: video.js

I use videojs and videojs-contrib-hls to play video in my website.

When a video's m3u8 file is loaded successfully and the broswer failed to get one of the ts file, videojs will retry over and over again, with log like this:

GET https://[my ts file url] 404(Not Found)
VIDEOJS: WARN: Problem encountered with the current HLS playlist. Trying again since it is the final playlist.

I want to listen to the error event and limit the retry.
Which event(on the player or .tech().hls) should I listen to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The videojs-http-streaming.js plugin (now included with videojs) has an undocumented event called "retryplaylist", you might try something like:

```
let retries = 0;
player.tech_.on('retryplaylist', () => {
   retries++;
   if (retries>=5)
     // do something
});
```

Comment: this is fine, but will it actually stop retries? ;)

Comment: Is there any better solution today? I have noticed that the 'retryplaylist' does not always fire for some reason.